# C++ Cycling includes (Three classes, two virtual)

Tags: c++, include, dependencies, abstract

I don´t know, how to declare some classes in my project, wich includings are cycling.

(Map -> Object -> Object_Manager -> Map ->...)

I found nothing (usefull) for three classes and tried some possibilities (many forms of forward declaration) for two classes - without success...

Here is my design for the classes (reduced form):

**Map.h**

```
//some other includes
#include "Object.h"

#ifndef Map_H
#define Map_H

class Map{
   public: 
     Map();
     virtual ~Map();
     void move_object(Object* object, int x, int y); 
     // some other functions and members, that should be usable for and with Objects
}
```

**Object.h**

```
#include "Object_Manager.h"

#ifndef Object_H
#define Object_H

class Object { 
   public:  
      Object();     
      virtual ~Object();
      void interact_with(Object* object); 
      //some other stuff

   protected: 
      Object_Manager* object_manager;  
}
```

**Object_Manager.h**

```
#include "Map.h"

class Object_Manager{
   public: 
      Object_Manager(); 
      ~Object_Manager(); 

      Map* map; 

      //some other stuff
}
```

Map.h (and its children) is using Objects in the .cpp and Object.h´s children are using Map* map from Object_Manager.h - if this is important.

With this code I get many compiler-ERRORs.
The compiler didn´t like my other solutions as well, so how could this work?

**Important**: what must stay in the .h and what in the .cpp files? And what is eventually needed for the child-classes?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you replace all 3 includes with the respective forward declaration? What is the compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove inclusion...

```
#include "Object_Manager.h"
```

From "Object.h" and use forward declaration instead...

```
class Object_Manager;
```

Similarly, remove inclusion...

```
#include "Map.h"
```

from "Object_Manager.h" and use forward declaration instead...

```
class Map;
```

Comment: I thought, I tried this already, but it works - maybe I forgot some remainings of other solutions earlier. 
Well, thank you very much!